# drf serializers, passing request to serializer context not working

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

this is the error I'm getting

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" of relation "recipes_recipe" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (24, testtest, test1234, 20, L, , f, null).

I understand the error but I don't get why it's happening.

When I try do this it doesn't work

```
# views.py
class RecipeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = RecipeSerializer
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {"user_id": self.request.user.id}



# serializers.py
class RecipeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = [
            "id",
            "user",
            "title",
            "description",
            "duration",
            "cost",
            "reference_link",
            "is_public",
        ]

        extra_kwargs = {"user": {"read_only": True}}

        def create(self, validated_data):
            return Recipe.objects.create(
                user_id=self.context["user_id"], **validated_data
            )
```

but when I Do this, it works!

```
# views.py
class RecipeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = RecipeSerializer
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user_id=self.request.user.id)



# serializers.py 
class RecipeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = [
            "id",
            "user",
            "title",
            "description",
            "duration",
            "cost",
            "reference_link",
            "is_public",
        ]

        extra_kwargs = {"user": {"read_only": True}}
```

can someone explain?